# Exec bad Access NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

`individualPercUpdated` is called on `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` and `checkInitialValue` is callled on `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin`. My prog crash on line  `if(!([initialValue isEqualToString:textField.text]))` by giving warning Exec Bad Access

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    initialValue=[[NSString alloc] init];
}

-(void) individualPercUpdated:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(initialValue!=nil){
        if(!([initialValue isEqualToString:textField.text])){
            initialValue=textField.text;
            NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
        }
    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
    }
}

-(void) checkInitialValue:(UITextField *)textField{
        initialValue=textField.text;
    }

}
```

Comment: where exactly does the crash occur?

Comment: if(!([initialValue isEqualToString:textField.text]))

Comment: you gotta retain `textView.text`, I suspect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace everywhere you use the instance variable with property and access it though it and you will not have any problems with the memory management.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *initialValue;
...
@synthesize initialValue = _initialValue;
....
//Access with:
self.initialValue = @"something";
```